# Как решить проблему с непрозрачностью?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь повторить такой fullscreen из макета хотя бы в общих чертах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пока до нижней кнопки не дошел. Проблема с прозрачностью фона. Вот, что получается на данный момент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура fullscreen

```
 <section class ="fullscreen">
<div class="fullscreen__body">
    
    <h3 class="fullscreen__title">Hello, I am</h3>
    <span class ="fullscreen__text fullscreen__text-gradient">John</span>
    <h2 class ="fullscreen__text">Smith</h2>
    <h3 class ="fullscreen__text fullscreen__text-small">I have more then 10 years of experience</h3>
    <a class="fullscreen__btn">download cv</a>
</div>
```

Стили :

```
.fullscreen{
display: flex;
min-height: 100vh;
flex: 1 1 auto;
min-width: 100vh;
background-color: #232d50;
}

   .fullscreen__body{
   min-height: 100vh;
   min-width: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   flex-direction: column;
   background-image:url("../images/fullscreen.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   margin: 0 auto;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   opacity: 0.2;
   }

.fullscreen__title {
color: #ebeced;
font-size: 40px;
letter-spacing: 10px;
z-index: 2;
}

.fullscreen__text {
color: #ebeced;
font-size: 45px;
letter-spacing: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 2;
}

.fullscreen__text-gradient{
color: #a21af0
letter-spacing: 20px;
font-size: 90px;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #a21af0, #ff0072);
-webkit-background-clip : text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
font-width: 700px;
}
```

из-за установки `.fullscreen__body opacity: 0.2` Непрозрачным стал весь блок. Установка непрозрачности в 1 для всего что находится в блоке не помогает. Как вернуть непрозрачность тексту, но при этом оставить opacity: 0.2 для фона?

Comment: Можно наоборот задать фон картинкой блоку .fullscreen, а .fullscreen__body - цвет фона с помощью rgba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.fullscreen {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../images/fullscreen.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.fullscreen__body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, .7);
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fullscreen__title {
  color: #ebeced;
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fullscreen__text {
  color: #ebeced;
  font-size: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fullscreen__text-gradient {
  color: #a21af0 letter-spacing: 20px;
  font-size: 90px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #a21af0, #ff0072);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<section class="fullscreen">
  <div class="fullscreen__body">
    <h3 class="fullscreen__title">Hello, I am</h3>
    <span class="fullscreen__text fullscreen__text-gradient">John</span>
    <h2 class="fullscreen__text">Smith</h2>
    <h3 class="fullscreen__text fullscreen__text-small">I have more then 10 years of experience</h3>
    <a class="fullscreen__btn">download cv</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно поверх элемента `.fullscreen` установить `div` c `position: absolute` и, используя свойста `top, left, bottom и right`, растянуть его на всю высоту и ширину родителя. Также установить свойство `backdrop-filter: opacity(0.2)` для него.

Подробнее тут:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/